# jQuery.parseJSON fails if single quote is part of response

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

Reading response object and the value has single quotes in it as below -

```
{"Offername":"One month Offer",
"OfferDescription":"One month's goodies free"}
```

Tried to add escape character but the above is valid `JSON` as per `jsonlint.com` but still `jQuery.parseJSON` fails with the above `JSON` with single apostrophe.

Appreciate any kind of response that helps me.

Comment: It does not / will not. Please show the *actual* JSON and the *actual* 'failing' code.

Comment: Can't repro: http://jsfiddle.net/15vvxnfr/1/. Are you sure jQuery didn't already parse the JSON and you are trying to parse an object?

Comment: i think you are parsing an Object.

Comment: Cerlin is right..you're parsing an object... try to set this response to a variable and try typeof...

Answer (score 0):

As one of the commenters said, you are having **object** instead of **string**. 
So you need to use the command `JSON.stringify` to convert it to a string.

> The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON
>   string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is
>   specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a
>   replacer array is specified. [More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Then, as you get a string (test it with typeof), you can parse it (NOTE: jQuery.Parse requires an string, not an object). [About](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5f06vtz4/)

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of converting the object to a string?

Comment: @FelixKling: CQCore had problems with parsing the response, right? He didn't post any code, only the problem with single quotes. So I tried to solve his problem in jsFiddle, when I found out that he has an type of OBJECT instead of string which jquery.ParseJSON needs (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) . The response he posted works with the solution I've posted. I also argumented what was wrong and what is the solution.

Comment: As you said, since they didn't post any code, we don't really know what is happening. That they parse an object is a *possibility*, but not fact. That said, *if* they have an object, then there is not need to convert that object to a string (JSON) to just convert it to an object again. Just use the object! I.e, instead of `obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`, just use `obj` and forget about JSON.